# How do you initialize a static reference class member in C++?

Tags: c++, reference, static

I have a class as below.

```
class MyClass
{
 public:
    static int &ref;
};
```

Now my question is, how do we initialize the ref variable of MyClass.
Reference variables are to be initialized using initializer list during object creation, where as static variables are initialized before object creation of a class since static variables are not bound to lifetime of any object of class.
Keeping these two concepts in mind, how do we initialize the ref in above class and how will the behavior of ref be?

Comment: It is the same as for other static class data members; the reference doesn't change anything. Search that topic to see code examples

Comment: "Reference variables are to be initialized using initializer list during object creation" - that is the rule for non-static variables only